# input:checked not being recognized after error

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

I made a group of radio buttons and checkboxes look like regular buttons with selected states that change the background color and font color when selected. It works fine unless you submit the form without selecting an answer. Once the error is applied, the browser no longer sees the first option (or all options for checkboxes) as being selected (input:checked + span is not being applied). Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

html:

```
<div class="surveyQuestion">
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("opinionBrand", "Excellent")<span>Excellent</span></label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("opinionBrand", "Good")<span>Good</span></label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("opinionBrand", "Fair")<span>Fair</span></label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("opinionBrand", "Poor")<span>Poor</span></label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton("opinionBrand", "Very Poor")<span>Very Poor</span></label>
</div>
```

css:

```
.surveyQuestion label {
    float:left;
    width:289px;
    margin: 0 9px 9px 0;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:2px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden; 
}

.surveyQuestion label input {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.surveyQuestion input:checked + span {
    background-color:#666;
    color: #fff;
}
```

script (error placement):

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

html (after error):

```
<label>
    <input id="opinionBrand" type="radio" value="Excellent" class="error">
    <label for="opinionBrand" class="error"></label>
    <span>Excellent</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input:checked + span` does mean that the span should be immediately after the `input:checked` (the `+`-sign). Use

```
.surveyQuestion input:checked + span,
.surveyQuestion input:checked + label.error + span {
    background-color:#666;
    color: #fff;
}
```

to match both with and without the error-label.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yigikunu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Wow that seems really obvious now that I see it. Thanks so much!